# node.js socket.io not broadcasting to the connected clients

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I have an application that receives messages from a program. This application receives the messages and in turn broadcasts the messages to the connected clients. Now i am displaying the messages on the console and on the console, this receiver application is receving perfectly. However on the client (the html page), it is not being broadcasted. When i open the localhost/result, nothing is displayed. What am i doing wrong?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var EventHubClient = require('azure-event-hubs').Client;
var connectionString = 'connection string';

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var printError = function (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
};

var result;

var printMessage = function (message) {
    console.log('Message received: ');
    result = JSON.stringify(message.body);
    obj = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log('message:' + result)

    console.log('');
};

count =0;

app.get('/result', function(req, res){

  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/result.html');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('user connected');

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){

     io.emit('chat message', result);
     console.log("This is id in the sock' section" + check_id);
  }); 
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
      socket.removeAllListeners('disconnect');
      io.removeAllListeners('connection');
  });
});

var client = EventHubClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
client.open()
    .then(client.getPartitionIds.bind(client))
    .then(function (partitionIds) {
        return partitionIds.map(function (partitionId) {
            return client.createReceiver('$Default', partitionId, {     'startAfterTime' : Date.now()}).then(function(receiver) {
                console.log('Created partition receiver: ' + partitionId)
                receiver.on('errorReceived', printError);
                receiver.on('message', printMessage);
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(printError);


http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

result.html

```
<html>
  <head><title>Hello world</title></head>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io();
  //  socket.emit('chat message')


    socket.on('chat message',function(msg){

        socket.emit('chat message',msg);
        document.write('hello world');
        document.write(msg);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried with the re-made example?

Comment: It workls fine. But why I don't understand that why it is working fine when the emit is triggered on a button click and not on document load?

Comment: because onload you should first connect the socket to the server and setup the clients socket-event handlers. Then inside the clients on 'connection' you know that socket is now connected, so inside that event you can start emitting.

Comment: If I have resolved your origianl question, please remember to mark it as solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would directly send it from the `printMessage` function :

```
function printMessage(message) {
 result = JSON.stringify(message.body);
 console.log('[message]',result);
 io.sockets.emit('chat message',result);
}
```

and remember to modify your client (`result.html`) so that it doesn't make an infinite loop :

```
<script>
var socket=io();
socket.on('chat message',function(msg){
 console.log(msg); //alert(msg);
 document.write(msg);
});
</script>
```

---

**EDIT :**

How are you including the **socket.io.js** script?

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Try and specify the server address `socket.connect('localhost:3000');`

[I made this working example for you](https://gist.github.com/unknown0perator/50d6746cfddcb9c5c917b7baa6ae06b2)

---

**RE-EDIT :** [I **remade** the working example for you, this time I added a client-server emission that bounces back to all connected clients](https://gist.github.com/unknown0perator/c689369601031acbb7e9cfda97fc4935).

Comment: Added a working example [gist](https://gist.github.com/unknown0perator/50d6746cfddcb9c5c917b7baa6ae06b2)

Comment: Thankyou for the answer but it still doesn't seem to work. When i do io.on('connection...) and print something, it works. However when i do, socket.on('chat message...) it does't work.

Comment: Hope the [re-made example with client-server emission](https://gist.github.com/unknown0perator/c689369601031acbb7e9cfda97fc4935) will help you figure out what you are doing wrong.. good luck :)